# How to know when html is totally load Vue 2

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, axios

I load some axios data (in the process to get this data, I throw a modal) to a html table, in the lower part of the table, I have a pagination but due to the html is not totally loaded, the pagination buttons don't work after some seconds (by this seconds, the html is freezed), how can I know if the html is totally loaded ?

When axios finish, finally function starts and hide the modal, but html is not load.

```
get_products_by_page(page_go_to){
        document.getElementById('modal-loading').style.display = 'block';
        axios.post('/intranet2/pedidos/search_data_product_stock_v2', {
            id_products: this.id_products[page_go_to], id_supplier_selected: this.id_supplier_selected, range_min: this.range_min, range_max: this.range_max
        }).then(function(response) {

            if(response.data.length != 0){
                this.current_page   = page_go_to;
                this.data_products  = response.data;

                this.$forceUpdate();

                try {
                    for (var i = 0; i < this.data_products.length; i++) {
                        document.getElementById('row'+this.data_products[i].id_product).style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                  //console.error(error);
                }
            
            }else{
                this.data_products = [];
                this.number_pages   = 0;
                this.total_products = 0;

                $.notify('Sin resultados.', 'info');
            }

        }.bind(this), function(response) {
            $.notify('Error al buscar productos.');
        }).finally(() => document.getElementById('modal-loading').style.display = 'none');
    },
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vue lifecycle hook updated().
The code should be something like

```
loadData() {
  lockPagination();
  apiRequest();
}

updated() {
 unlockPagination();
}
```